# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `pyautogui`

Tags: python, module

I appreciate questions similar to this one (for VSCode and PyCharm) but I'm experiencing a problem with SublimeText with the following code:

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(5)
f = open("text", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui, time 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

I tried googling it but I couldn't find the answer, Please help! Thank you!

Comment: have you tried installing `pyautogui`?

Comment: For instructions on how to install a module, see https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run `pip install pyautogui`